# how to create Short Url in Mediawiki?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mediawiki

My mediawiki's localproject name is "wiki_test".and i use following code for localsettins.php file

```
$wgScriptPath = "/wiki_test";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
require_once("$IP/extensions/ShortUrl/ShortUrl.php"); //
```

and create one file in the root(means in my project folder) .htaccess file.and put following code in that

```
RewriteEngine On
# Short url for wiki pages
#RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mediawiki_test/index.php/ [L]
# Redirect / to Main Page
RewriteRule ^/*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/mediawiki_test/index.php [L]
```

and try for short url but give error like"Object not found!". so plz give me idea........

Comment: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Short_url

Comment: but sir that not work for me,.......i try that page all code

Comment: Please provde a bit more information then. What is the working long url? is mod_rewrite enabled and actually working?

Comment: hey @mahi, have you finally solved this? I am facing the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing your .htaccess in `mediawiki_test` directory then this code should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mediawiki_test/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: For which URL it didn't work? What is location of this htaccess file?